# Program is not execute in python 2.7.3 { RESTART: C:/Python27/kushagra.py}

Tags: python

Whenever I write a program in python it shows an error in idle. A python 2.7.3 error.
 program is given below:

```
import turtle
def draw_square():

window = turtle.Screen()

window.bgcolor("red")

brad = turtle.Turtle()
brad.forward(100)
brad.right(90)
brad.forward(100)
brad.right(90)
brad.forward(100)
brad.right(90)
brad.forward(100)
brad.right(90)

window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

the error is given below:

```
RESTART: C:/Python27/kushagra.py
```

[image]

Comment: show us a minimal example of a program you cannot run.

Comment: Are you saying that "RESTART: C:/Python27/kushagra.py" is the complete error message? But didn't you say that "it is very complicated"? It looks quite short to me. If you're thinking "there are more lines to the error message, but they're so complicated that I didn't mention them because there's no way anybody could understand them", please don't leave them out. Error messages exist to be understood.

Comment: so please help because i did not execute my programs in python

Comment: We need to see your program to help you fix it. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: import turtle
def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    
    window.exitonclick()

    draw_square()

Comment: If you want to add code to your question, please edit your question instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: have you find the solution ?

Comment: I'm still waiting for you to answer my questions and post the complete error message.

Comment: now it is done tell me the solution of error

Comment: That's better, but you **still** haven't posted the error message. Your code isn't indented properly. If you fix the indentation it will work on Python 2 or Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with my requests. One more thing: I don't usually ask for this, but can you upload a screenshot of the IDLE window? I suspect there is more diagnostic information being displayed but not anywhere that you're thinking of looking.

Comment: now did you detect the solution?

Comment: @kevin Did you answer me ?

Comment: `RESTART: C:/Python27/kushagra.py` isn't an error message. When I run you program in idle3 (after I fix the indentation) I get a similar message, but I also get a Turtle red window opening, with a turtle drawing a black square.

Comment: so what can i do tell me please!!!!

Comment: Is the indentation of the code in your question exactly 100% identical to the indentation of the code in your IDLE window? So you have `def draw_square():` with no indentation, and then `window = turtle.Screen()` with no indentation as well? If not, please edit your question so the indentation is exactly as it appears on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is indented like this:

```
import turtle
def draw_square():

    window = turtle.Screen()

    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)

    window.exitonclick()

    draw_square()
```

... Then executing this program in IDLE will give you this output:

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
================== RESTART: C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\test.py ==================
>>>
```

Because no code is actually running. `draw_square()` never gets called because it's indented inside the `draw_square` definition. Un-indent it so it's at the file-level scope instead.

```
import turtle
def draw_square():

    window = turtle.Screen()

    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```

Now you should get the turtle window you desire.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin it is works

Comment: Thanks to that answer I now understand why so many OPs post the "RESTART" trace and think that it's an error message... it's just an IDLE thing to tell that the program is started...